# Error Occuring On Tensorflow Installation

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I installed tensorflow in r for several times yet the modeling sequential part is not working. The modeling part is showing installation error. How can I resolve the problem in r language?

```
install_tensorflow()
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model%>%layer_flatten(input_shape = c(lookback / step, dim(data)[-1])) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\NIE12\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\r-tensorflow\python.exe
 C:\Python27\python.exe
 C:\Python27\python.exe
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\Users\NIE12\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\TensorFlowEnv\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

Comment: you need to install tensorflow which is a python package. try `install_tensorflow()` as instructed.

Comment: I already did that as u can see in the code.

Comment: what's the output from executing `install_tensorflow()`. is it a success? by the way how you run the function before you load the library?